# What is the += / -= mean in a delegate data structure in c#?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, threadpool

If I have this code:

```
genetic = new Genetic();
genetic.foundNewBestGroupTour += new Genetico.NewBestGroupTourEventHandler(genetico_foundNewBestGroupTour);
```

What does the `+=` do?

```
genetic.foundNewBestGroupTour -= new Genetico.NewBestGroupTourEventHandler(genetico_foundNewBestGroupTour);
```

What does the `-=` do?

Comment: Please read http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read up on [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx).

The `+=` operator in this context calls the event `add` accessor, while `-=` calls the `remove` accessor. This is usually called *subscribing* and *unsubscribing* to the event.

The usual way to implement an event is to have a backing field which holds a multicast delegate, in this case of type `Genetico.NewBestGroupTourEventHandler`. The accessors mentioned add and remove from the "invocation list" of this multicast delegate field.

Comment: Yes, but how does '-= new' know to remove an existing event? 
Usually new is used to make a new class.
What if there were 3 events which one would '-= new' remove?

Comment: @AriesConnolly That is a good question. I think the answer is rather technical. If the `remove` accessor is written "by hand", all depends on the code in that accessor. In the more common case of a field-like event, the event has a backing field of delegate type. Then ultimately it comes down to "subtraction" (binary operator `-`) of two delegates, the one in the backing field, and the one you pass in. See [subtraction operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#subtraction-operator) under delegate removal in the C# spec.

Comment: To answer the last part of your comment, it is a part of the link I provided, that the __last__ one of the instances, and only it, would be removed, in the case where there are 3 matching "entries" in the invocation list of the delegate in the backing field.

Answer (score 1):

It's used to subscribe / unsubscribe (bind / unbind) to an event.

```
genetic.foundNewBestGroupTour += genetico_foundNewBestGroupTour
```

Subscribes (binds) an event handler so that the method `genetico_foundNewBestGroupTour` will be called whenever the `foundNewBestGroupTour` event is raised on `genetic`.

```
genetic.foundNewBestGroupTour -= genetico_foundNewBestGroupTour;
```

Unsubscribes (unbinds) the handler. After this code is executed, the method `genetico_foundNewBestGroupTour` will be no longer be called when the `foundNewBestGroupTour` event is raised on `genetic`.

**Further Reading**

- [How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

They are the compiler shorthand for adding and removing events.

Comment: Shorthand, yes, but also the only legal syntax for doing this in C# (disregarding reflection).

Comment: I guess I meant that by "compiler shorthand". I'll have to tell my local barrista to make my morning coffee stronger :)