# What happens if you put functions from two classes in one delegate?

Tags: c#, class, namespaces, delegates, public

I am preparing for an exam and I have to examine various codes. One is about delegates in C# - I'm failing to see what it does, since I don't know if you can put functions from two different classes in one delegate.

Here's the code:

```
namespace konzolnaApplikacijaDelegateVoidMain {

public delegate int MyDelegate(int x);

class Program
{

    public int number;

    public Program (int x)
    {
        number = x;
    }

    public int Add(int x)
    {
        return x + 10;
    }

    public int Substract(int x)
    {
        return x - 10;
    }

    public int Multiply(int x)
    {
        return x * 2;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyDelegate delegate;
        Program first = new Program(20);
        Program second = new Program(50);

        delegate = first.Add;
        delegate += second.Add;
        delegate -= first.Substract;
        delegate += second.Multiply;
        delegate += first.Add;

        delegate(first.number);
        delegate(second.number);

        Console.Write("{0}", first.number + second.number);


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don’t expect this code will compile since “delegate” is a C# keyword, but is being used as a variable in your example. With that being said, I think that the answer to the question linked below will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391414/why-dont-i-see-the-operator-overloaded-on-system-delegate

Comment: Also check this question out. It covers how both the += and -= operators work on delegates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935299/what-is-the-mean-in-a-delegate-data-structure-in-c

Comment: Combining non-`void` delegates together into a multicast delegate is a recipe for disaster. There are various "right" answers for what should be returned from them and you're not guaranteed that any of the answers you want are what .NET gives you out of the box. (mind, in this case, you're also ignoring the return value, so there's that too)

Comment: Note, even the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/how-to-combine-delegates-multicast-delegates) on them fails to mention return values

Comment: My mistake, consider that instead of "delegate" it says "dg". I wanted to know if this code will only return the value of the last method that is subscribed?

Comment: Actually, this is what the professor gives us for the test. He wants to check our understanding of the code. Even though sometimes the codes don't make sense at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegates are quite simple. Consider the following implementation of a delegate.

```
namespace DelegateExamples
{
    class Program
    {
        //Declare a integer delegate to handle the functions in class A and B
        public delegate int MathOps(int a, int b);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MathOps multiply = ClassA.Multiply;
            MathOps add = ClassB.Add;
            int resultA = multiply(30, 30);
            int resultB = add(1000, 500);
            Console.WriteLine("Results: " + resultA + " " + resultB);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    public class ClassA
    {
        public static int Multiply(int a, int b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
    }
    public class ClassB
    {
        public static int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of the question is unclear to me, but the one thing that does seem to be clear is that they're asking about *combining* delegates, i.e. creating multicast delegates. As such, I cannot see what this answer is addressing. And you've not really provided any *explanation* about why this should answer their question.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to know what was the return value of the given code... In some of the material I found, it says that it will return only the value of the last method that is added (subscribed) to the delegate. Is this true?